# How to I add hierarchical custom setting for Automated Process user?

Tags: customsetting, automated-process

Given a hierarchical custom setting and a desire to include an entry for User = Automated Process, when I use the UI, I get this error:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason you might need to do this is that Platform Event subscribers run in the context of the Automated Process user.  To enable the custom setting entry at the user level, you need to insert a row into the SObject using Developer Console, anonymous Apex, Data Loader, Workbench or the like.

1. First, find the ID of the User record  corresponding to the Automated Process user: `SELECT Id, Name FROM User WHERE Name = 'Automated Process'`
2. Then insert a row as follows:

   ```
   SetupOwnerId = theIdOfTheAutomatedProcessUser
   Field1__c = ...
   Field2__c = ...
   ```

In the Developer Console, this might look like this:

[image]

Once you do this, the entry will appear in the Setup UI and you can edit or delete

[image]

Comment: Nice and simple. Could data load too for those so inclined.